# Postfix: Send email to PHP

Tags: php, postfix-mta

Greetings,

Anyone know of a good way to send an email to my postfix server which then opens a PHP script to process this email? I could do cron, but I'd prefer to do it instantly...

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer all new e-mails to a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258677/transfer-all-new-e-mails-to-a-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use a .forward, but probably the easiest way is to configure procmail.

Edit: here's a sample .procmailrc rule that may help:

```
:0 w
* ^From.*authorized@example.com
| php /path/to/script.php
```

If the email comes from authorized@example.com, then it will get passed to the php script.  Since this is done from procmail which can be integrated with the mail server, the MySql setup shouldn't impact anything.

Comment: I'll certainly have a look at procmail. It looks very scary though! The problem I have is that I have a vmail folder which contains email for all my users. I've a Postfix/MySQL setup

Answer (score 1):

When setting up something like this, you have 2 options.  You can either pipe mail out to a php handler, which is a little dangerous if you have to process a lot of mail at once, or you get mailbombed.  Like @B Mitch said, a .forward file will do the trick.

> myemail@example.com,"|/our/script.php"

Alternatively, can you use something like `Zend_Mail_Storage` to connect to a mailbox as if it were a client.  [Zend](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html) also supplies some useful helpers for parsing mail.

Comment: Good point about getting mailbombed. I'm thinking of using inotify to monitor my /home/vmail folder for changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options; the easiest being to use a .forward file containing:
|/path/to/your/script
in the $HOME of your user.

Drawback: It's invoked once per mail
Advantage: It's called with exactly one recipient and many parameters are passed using environment variables.