# Execute php script on receiving e-mail

Tags: php, apache, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Postfix: Send email to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964600/postfix-send-email-to-php)

I want a php script to be executed when i receive an email to an account associated with my domain.

My site is hosted on Apache with php is using Google Apps(Free)

Comment: You need to configure your MTA (sendmail / postfix) to pipe into the PHP script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Varun!

Answer (score 0):

Look into [procmail](http://procmail.org).  That offers the type of functionality that you're looking for.  It's a linux package, but it does what you need.

Here's a good tutorial to get you started: http://userpages.umbc.edu/~ian/procmail.html#gettingstarted

Comment: Thanx everybody for helping, but i am not so expert in all these stuff. so, is there is an easy way for me to do so.